# Datatable header Okay but body connecting Datatable to Api - not returning data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, api, datatable, asp.net-ajax

These are my errors in the browser:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

jquery.datatables.js:3406 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

[image]

Here's the JSON response direct:

[image]

Here's the source for the page:

```html
@model IEnumerable<SE01.Models.BMFixture>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fixtures";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Fixtures</h2>

<table id="bmfixtures" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Selection</th>
            <th>Bookmaker</th>
            <th>Odds</th>
            <th>Delete</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
           
    </tbody>
</table>


@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#bmfixtures").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/Api/BMFixtures",
                    datasrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "marketname",
                        render: function(data, type, bmfixture) {
                            return "<a href='/bmfixtures/edit/" + bmfixture.Id + "'>" + bmfixture.marketname + "</a>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "marketname"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "selectionname"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "bookmakername"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "bookmakerodds"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function(data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-bmfixture-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                        }
                    }

                ]
            });

            $("#bmfixtures").on("click", " .js-delete", function () {
                var button = $(this);

                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this fixture?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/bmfixtures/" + button.attr("data-bmfixture-id"),
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function () {
                            button.parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I tried a simple demo and it appears to be working fine, however I'm not using you data, so maybe an issue with JSON format. Only things I did differently are to use single quotes and fully qualify the url - so try (e.g. `url: "http://localhost:60241/api/bmfixtures"`)

Example (have changed data in links etc. just so you get idea):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fixtures";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Fixtures</h2>

<table id="bmfixtures" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>text</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>

        $("#bmfixtures").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                // Replace below line with: url: "http://localhost:60241/api/bmfixtures", (in your version)
                url: "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd",
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    render: function (data, type, bmfixture) {
                        return "<a href='/bmfixtures/edit/" + bmfixture.id + "'>" + bmfixture.id + "</a>";
                    }
                },
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'type' },
                { data: 'text' },
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    render: function (data) {
                        return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-bmfixture-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERy much indeed @James

I worked right through the night & completely rebuilt the system from the ground up for a clean start (there was another data issue as well) and low and behold the problem still persisted...UNTIL I started playing around with the columns starting off with just the one column and building it up gradually.

Low and behold, it works when I remove the href - as you indicated. Funny thing I tried it with single quotes when you said but it didnt work.

At least I know it works and that's where the problem lies - I will experiment further.

You're a star!

Comment: This is showing the nub of the problem James - I don't know how to incorporate the variable into the edit href - see -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374866/dynamic-link-in-datatables-column-returning-undefined

Comment: Thank you James  - for your answer - It should be id (lower case) not Id.